# PHP PDO using try

Tags: php

For best practices should I be putting the fetch command portion inside of the try statement or is the prepare and execute sufficient?

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE device = 'mobile' AND category = ? ORDER BY category asc, link_id asc";

try{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(1, $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
} 
catch(\PDOException $ex){
    print($ex->getMessage()); 
}

if($sth->rowCount()) {        
    print("<a data-rel=\"dialog\" data-transition=\"pop\" href=\"index.php?action=addnew&cat=$cat\">Add New Menu Item</a><br/><br/>");
    print("<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-filter=\"true\">");
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {    
        print("<li>");
        print("<a data-transition='fade' href='$row[$COL_HREF]'>$row[$COL_LINK_NAME]<br/></a>");
        print("</li>\n");
    }
    print("</ul>");
}
```

Comment: Pleasing to the eyes to see a PDO query for a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `try` with the rest of the code.

If the code in your `try` produces an Exception, you're printing out the exception message but are then continuing to check the `rowCount()`, which is dependent on `$sth` being successfully set and executed.